# Spring Security "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" with two child contexts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring application using Spring Security and I'm running into issues with two child contexts. It seems as if Spring Security is only properly initializing one context. The specific error is "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" and only happens on one of the two contexts.

There's a possibility I caused this problem myself when creating a custom delegating filter proxy, so I'll elaborate on the custom filter first and then explain the problem I'm staring at now.

NOTE: All configuration done in XML

Spring version: 3.2.5

Spring Security version: 3.2.5

We have a root context and two child contexts, module1 and module2. Each child context is using the "security:http" element with a pattern to restrict to its module's URL space. The two aspects of these child contexts that require them being child contexts are a custom pre-authentication filter to hook into our existing authentication code and a custom role voter on the access decision manager to do per-module authorization via database. The modules exist in a mixed Struts / Spring application, most modules under Struts but module1 and module2 here under Spring.

The security configuration must be stored in the child contexts since we use component scans per module and  each module has its own role voter.

Separating everything like this worked for module1, but when we introduced module2 the standard delegating filter proxy was causing issues since it could only delegate to one context. I introduced a custom delegating filter proxy that could select which context based on the URL. It is configured like this in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>somecompany.CustomDelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>availableContexts</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /app/module1,
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.module1-rest,
            /app/module2,
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.module2-rest
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>defaultContext</param-name>
            <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.module1-rest
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
```

I thought this addressed all the issues with the two modules since application seemed fine. Using the standard delegating filter proxy, the application won't start and server shows the error "No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined". Defining this bean manually in root context or in either/both of the child contexts did not solve the problem.

When revisiting to add our custom RBAC code to module2, the "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" error happens. I've been tracing through Spring's code and I'm fairly certain what's going on is the "defaultContext" in the delegating filter proxy is where all the Spring Security set up is done, since this is the context used by the custom filter proxy when the URL does not match either pattern listed. Whichever of the two modules is specified as the default is where Spring Security works just fine. Application start up doesn't usually hit either of these modules first.

My question is two fold:

1. Is the custom delegating filter proxy I have a viable solution? I tried many configuration options to get both modules working correctly and settled on needing to select which context to use, though with the problems I'm now encountering I'm concerned this solution isn't viable. If it isn't, or if there's a way to simply fix the delegating filter proxy, that would be a useful answer.
2. If the filter proxy is viable, how would I then go about ensuring Spring Security is properly working in both modules? I'm not seeing the security filter chain executing in the second module, most significantly the security context persistence handler, thus no authentication data and the error in the question. I've tried different session configuration options and different repositories for the security context but nothing works.

Configuration is near same for both modules. Spring security configured like this:

```
<security:http pattern="/module1/api/**" create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
</security:http>
```

The web.xml file contains only the custom springSecurityFilterChain, our custom delegating filter proxy. The application-context.xml file only contains a few data sources for use in our application. Each child context, module1-rest.xml and module2-rest.xml, has component scans for our dependency injection and the spring security configuration.

Any insight is appreciated